# Iterating the ListView and change content of some rows (ListItem)

Tags: android, listview

I have a ListView whose ListItems(RelativeLayout) have 
A `textView` and two `ImageButton`s inside a LinearLayout.

Here is the xml of my ListItem;

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/list_item_quote"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="15dp"
        android:paddingTop="15dp"
        style="@style/quote_text"
        />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/lytShareLike"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/list_item_quote"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/list_item_quote"
        android:layout_alignRight="@id/list_item_quote"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/list_item_quote">

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:id="@+id/btnShare"
        android:background="@null"
        android:onClick="quoteShareClick"
        android:src="@drawable/share"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        />
    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:id="@+id/btnLike"
        android:background="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/heartnot"
        android:onClick="quoteLikeClick"

        />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I have `ItemClickListener` which sets the `LinearLayout` visible when the ListItem is clicked. There is no problem until here.

What I want to do is, after clicking a ListItem, if the user clicks another ListItem, the other unclicked Listitems' `LinearLayouts` should be **GONE** again.

Here is my onClickListener;

```
listQuotes.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                                    long id) {
                LinearLayout lytShareLike = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.lytShareLike);

                for (int i = 0; i < listQuotes.getAdapter().getCount(); i++) {
                    if (position != i && i != 0) {
                        LinearLayout lnrTemp = (LinearLayout) listQuotes.getAdapter().getView(i, null, null).findViewById(R.id.lytShareLike);
                        lnrTemp.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

The for iteration iterates the items and `LinearLayouts` as expected but the `LinearLayouts` are still **VISIBLE**

What am I missing?

Comment: "if (position != i && i != 0)" can you give some clarification for this line? Also try to check all list items, then uncheck one, and report what you see. Do some layouts exit the screen, or are all of them still visible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can control it by using below code：

```
//...
int index = -1;
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    index = position;
    mAdaper..notifyDataSetChanged();
}
//...
```

in the adapter：

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        //...
        Holder holder;
        if(convertView == null) {
            convertView = ....;
            holder = new Holder(convertView);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        holder = (Holder) convertView.getTag();

        if(index == position){
            holder.linearLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            holder.linearLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        //...
        return convertView;
    }
```

Comment: What is holder ? Can not reslove 'Holder'

Comment: It is only used to enhance the efficiency of listview, you can define your own or do not use it, what u should be concerned about is to be achieved by controlling the variableto in the adapter be equal with the position u clicked，and notify it to update.Just like what i said just now.